# Two-way data binding of text box focus with DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

In a WPF application built by the MVVM principle, I need to explicitly set the focus to a TextBox from code (reacting on a keyboard event), and also know whether focus has been lost. From another question here I have gathered that appearently the way to do this is with data binding on a DependencyProperty. For that I have picked up the following code:

```cs
public static class FocusHelper
{
    public static bool GetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(FocusHelper),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uie = (UIElement)d;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            uie.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

The TextBox binding looks like this:

```cs
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.Group}" helper:FocusHelper.IsFocused="{Binding RowData.Row.GroupFocused, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

This is in a (DevExpress) grid; `Row` is the actual ViewModel the entire row is bound to.

The corresponding code in the bound ViewModel:

```cs
private bool groupFocused;

public bool GroupFocused
{
    get { return this.groupFocused; }

    set
    {
        this.groupFocused = value;
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.GroupFocused);
    }
}
```

When the keyboard event is handled, `GroupFocused` is set to true, which sure enough invokes the DependencyProperty callback and sets the focus to the TextBox. When the control loses focus, however, that change is not reflected back on the ViewModel (the DependencyProperty's callback is also not invoked).

Is there any obvious reason for this behavior? Anything wrong with the code?

(I have tried adding `UpdateSourceTrigger` with both `PropertyChanged` and `LostFocus` to the binding, also changing the DependencyProperty's default value to `true`, none of which changed anything about the behavior. I also tried `IsKeyboardFocused` instead of `IsFocused` with no change, and `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`, which made the application close with no comment - likely a DevExpress exception - on assembling the grid.)

Comment: I don't see any link between the actual `IsFocused` (of the `TextBox`, not of your helper class) (or some handler for focusing event) and the viewmodel's property here. So how could it reflect that to the viewmodel?

Comment: From my understanding, that link is made with using `IsFocused` as the name of the DependencyProperty and and binding it to `GroupFocused` in the ViewModel - and that link appears to exist, because the binding works in one direction.

Comment: I mean the actual `IsFocused` of your `TextBox`. When your TextBox focusing information changes, that's the only source to get that state. Here we don't see that source exists. In other words, now you have some way to set the Focusing state but not get it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not data binding your `GroupFocused` property to the `TextBox.IsFocused` property, you are data binding it to the `FocusHelper.IsFocused` property, *which programmatically calls `Focus` on the `TextBox`*.

There's a distinct difference. Calling the `Focus` method on the `TextBox` *will* result in the `TextBox.IsFocused` property being set to `true`, but there is no connection between that property and either your `GroupFocused` or your `FocusHelper.IsFocused` properties, so neither will be set to `false` when the `TextBox.IsFocused` property is set to `false`.

Furthermore, you cannot data bind to the `TextBox.IsFocused` property in an attempt to set the focus because it is read only. See the [`UIElement.IsFocused` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isfocused(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for more information on that.

However, there is a simple solution. It might not look pretty, but it will certainly work... just set the `GroupFocused` property to `false` before you set it to true each time. Perhaps something like this:

```
private void FocusTextBox()
{
    GroupFocused = false;
    GroupFocused = true;
}
```

...

```
FocusTextBox();
```

Comment: I think I begin to understand. Setting the property to `false` immediately before setting it to `true` doesn't change anything, though. (I also don't understand why you'd expect it to.)

Comment: You're not quite correct, it *does* do one thing... setting the property to `false` simply allows you to set it to `true` again afterwards. When it's already `true`, you just can't set it to `true` and trigger the call to `Focus`.

Comment: I meant to say that I tried it and it doesn't change the behavior. The problem is, and I haven't mentioned that yet, that there is other code that depends on whether the text box has focus, so I need to be able to query the current status at any time.

Comment: Then you should also data bind a `bool` property to the `TextBox.IsFocused` property directly.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do here. (As will likey be obvious, I am completely new to WPF, dealing with DependencyProperties for the first time and rather lost.) How would I go about that? IntelliSense doesn't show it in XAML, presumably because it is readonly.

Comment: See the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.